# Difference between cloudapp.net and azurewebsites.net

Tags: azure

I wrote code like below. It works when I publish it as cloudapp.net, but throw SEHException when I publish it as azurewebsites.net.

```
String val = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("myconfig");
```

So what's the difference between these 2 domains/publish approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link answers my question:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-application-models/

Especially the [What Should I Use part](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-application-models/#WhatShouldIUse).

I deployed my application as a Web Site rather than a cloud service. So the `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable = False` as expected, which means the application is actually not running with Azure runtime.